Is it possible to connect an Android phone to an Android tablet, and use the phone as a scanner for an app on the tablet?
I'm using an inventory management app on an Android tablet, such as "Stock and Inventory Online".
Would I be able to connect over Bluetooth to another Android phone, and use the phone as a barcode scanner that integrates into the app?
Basically, I'm trying to see if an Android phone can replace the function of a Bluetooth barcode scanner, such as one shown below.


Generally users want to use a physical barcode scanner for better range/ergonomics so using a secondary Android device is very use case dependant.
Disclaimer I haven't used OP's linked product but will describe options

Device A: tablet/device with the inventory software
Device B: other Android device to act as scanner

So the software on Device A needs to be able to get info from the Bluetooth scanner. How the inventory software communicate/interacts with the bluetooth scanner is important to find out.
Traditional Bluetooth Scanner can communicate in one of two ways:

Barcode Scanner Manufacturer specific Bluetooth API / Android specific SDK.
Acting as a Bluetooth Keyboard (Bluetooth HID).

Therefore the inventory software on Device A needs be able to handle one of the two above options. So Device B will need to be able to communicate in a similar fashion.
Research is required if Barcode Scanner Manufacturer Bluetooth API / Android SDK is public / used by the Inventory Software.
Legacy USB wired Barcode Scanners typically had configuration barcodes for setup state and for formatting the scanned barcode data which was sent to the sales register. Formatting with special characters was required for the sales register software to know that data was from a physical barcode scanner. My expectation is the same for Bluetooth Barcode Scanner devices with possibly a specialized soft keyboard app on Device A.
Consumer Android devices acting as a Bluetooth Keyboard may be device dependent as documented here
So depending on how the inventory software on Device A accepts data, you may be able to use Device B as a scanner, i.e. specialized software on Device B which will scan a barcode, decode it and then transmit over bluetooth to Device A.
Do note that software recommendations are off-topic here.

If I purchased any generic no-name bluetooth scanner in the market, would they more likely work a certain way? In this case, would it more likely be like a form of a bluetooth keyboard? This might help me narrow down a solution.

I would deeply review any documentation for any scanner to see if my description about workflow matches. Searching on the make/model number for related forums for users with direct experience is a path to try. Again how your particular inventory software will integrate with the scanner is what you need to figure out (or pay a system integrator to do it for you).
